# How do you get back from Z8N-TP?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I can get TO the CL4PTP unit  in Tycho's Ribs for it's quest but when I try to use the jumppad to get back, it always tosses me into the rotating spire in the middle and instakills me. I have tried aming in all directions but i still get hit by the spire.

Anyone know how you should get back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a series that mocks jumping puzzles (in Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep), the Borderlands games certainly do have some annoying ones.

That return jump is difficult. You need to time is just right to avoid the rotating spire. I remember dying numerous times trying that, until I learned the trick: just exit the game and rejoin it. This should deposit you at the beginning of the level, where you can continue with the quest.

Start [this video walk-through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE93h6vCPjo) at about 1:45 to see a discussion of this technique.